# PHPMailer keeps returning error

Tags: php, email, mailer

This is my php file:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$mail -> isSMTP();
$mail->PluginDir = "/path/to/phpmailer/dir";
$mail -> SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail -> Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail -> SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail -> Port = 465;
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail -> Username = "xxx"; //username example@gmail.com
$mail -> password = "xxx"; //password

$mail -> setFrom("autobandendiscount@gmail.com", "Anwar Elbouhdifi");
$mail -> addAddress($email, $name);



$mail -> Subject = $subject;
$mail -> Body = $message;
$mail -> AltBody = $message;

if(! $mail -> send()){
    echo"message error: " . $mail -> ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo"Success!" ;
}

}
```

?>

And the mailer returns this error

> 2014-05-28 22:51:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2014-05-28 22:51:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2014-05-28 22:51:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: YXV0b2JhbmRlbmRpc2NvdW50QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 2014-05-28 22:51:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: 2014-05-28 22:51:05 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 r5sm46692086wjq.26 - gsmtp 2014-05-28 22:51:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT SMTP connect() failed. message error: SMTP connect() failed.

I know it says username and password not accepted but I know for 100% it is the right password and username.

Comment: You may think you are entering the username and password correct but Google is telling you that you are not.  Check the link they provided to try to resolve it by signing in directly.

Comment: Is it something as simple as starting password with a capital letter e.g. Password?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the solution but worth a try: spell Password with a big P.

Comment: If this solved the problem, plase mark as 'accpeted' :)